# How to get data for a sample of images on a page?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have a few images displayed as a basic slider.

I'd like to retrieve some text related to the currently displayed image (#current_item img)

At the moment i thought about sending a request to the database everytime the user interacts with the slider. But i'm concerned it might use too much resources?

I'd like to find an easier way to retrieve this info (Title and Description) without sending a request to the database.*

Any way to achieve this?

```
<div class="gallery-wrapper">
    <div class="gallery-inner">
        <div class="gallery_item" id="prev_item">
            <img src="..." alt="" class="gallery_image">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery_item" id="current_item">
            <img src="..." alt="" class="gallery_image">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery_item" id="next_item">
            <img src="..." alt="" class="gallery_image">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="button prev">ARCHITECTURE</div>
<div class="button next">PEOPLE</div>
```

Comment: ideally you could have that title and description already in the html and not request it on sliding..

Comment: ... if you worry about html size for example for mobile phones gzip it..

Comment: Are you talking about adding a figcaption to each image or create a hidden div that would be shown depending on the current image? Or i completly misunderstood?

Comment: Yes more or less like that yes..

Comment: Thank you Raymond. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: you could pre-fetch the data, save it on a variable as json, and let the slider refer to it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @rai. As a global variable or in local storage maybe?